# no transition effect on mouse over and mouse out with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I use transition effect for a div to make it change smoothly on scroll down, but I don't want this transition effect to be used when I mouse over or mouse out as the div is used as a button. I could omit this effect from mouse over, but I couldn't do anything for mouse out:

HTML Code:

```
<div class="navButton"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.navButton {
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.navButton.scroll {
    top:100px;
}
.navButton:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```

and jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
      $(window).scroll(function(event){
        if($(this).scrollTop() > 400){
            $('.navButton').addClass('scroll');
        }; 
      });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to toggle a class on `mouseover`/`mouseout`:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ezmbw6bd/)

```
$('.navButton').on('mouseover mouseout', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('no-transition');
});
```

```
.no-transition {
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```

---

You could alternatively, just transition the `top` property:

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/n7b5qtud/)

```
.navButton {
    position: absolute;
    top:10px;
    -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are only trying to apply the transition to the `top` increase, you can target `top` intead of `all`:[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gcxt6yp0/)

```
  -webkit-transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
    transition: top 0.5s ease-in-out;
```